# Returning ID from the upsert procedure in language sql postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, stored-procedures, sql-function

I have a SQL upsert query and I want to return inserted record ID or updated record ID of the locations table. What changes do I need in the query? (Note: the `name` column is unique)

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE locations_upsert
(
    _name        TEXT,
    _address     TEXT,
    _postal_code TEXT,
    _country     TEXT
)
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
    INSERT INTO locations
    (
        name,
        address,
        postal_code,
        country
    )
    VALUES
    (
        _name,
        _address,
        _postal_code,
        _country
    )
    ON CONFLICT (name)
    DO UPDATE  
    SET 
        address = _address,
        postal_code = _postal_code,
        country = _country
$$;
```

Comment: Use a function `returns bigint`

Comment: Use `RETURNING id` in the function. For more information see Postgres documents: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-insert.html

Comment: Thank you both. Question: Is it not possible with procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A procedure cannot return a value. Change the procedure to a function and declare it as `int` or `bigint` as return type:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION locations_upsert(
  _name        TEXT,
  _address     TEXT,
  _postal_code TEXT,
  _country     TEXT
) RETURNS bigint
AS $$ 
  INSERT INTO locations  
    (name, address, postal_code, country) VALUES
    (_name,_address,_postal_code,_country)
   ON CONFLICT (name)
   DO UPDATE SET 
     address = _address,
     postal_code = _postal_code,
     country = _country
   RETURNING id;    
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Alternatively you can use the table name as return data type - `RETURNS locations` -, which will enable you to return the whole record - `RETURNING *`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION locations_upsert(
  _name        TEXT,
  _address     TEXT,
  _postal_code TEXT,
  _country     TEXT
) RETURNS locations
AS $$ 
  INSERT INTO locations  
    (name, address, postal_code, country) VALUES
    (_name,_address,_postal_code,_country)
    ON CONFLICT (name)
    DO UPDATE SET 
      address = _address,
      postal_code = _postal_code,
      country = _country
  RETURNING *;  
$$ LANGUAGE sql;
```

Demo: [`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=03aba9c188a016a878dab35ebab194cf)

Further reading: [`PostgreSQL CREATE PROCEDURE`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-create-procedure/)

Comment: This is working, thank you :). Is it not possible with procedure instead of function?

Comment: @kiran no, procedures cannot return any value.

Answer (score 2):

Change definition of procedure to function which returns integer value and use

```
INSERT INTO ... RETURNING id

UPDATE ... RETURNING id
```

expression.